Need access to user in RouteServiceProvider
I am working on an api for an existing multi-tenant application. I want to bind all models in the RouteServiceProvider so that they are always scoped to a team:
       Route::bind('item', function ($value) use ($teamId) {
              $item = Item::where('items.id', $value)
                  ->where('items.team_id', $teamId)
                  ->firstOrFail();

              if (!$item) {
                  abort(404);
              }

              return $item;
          });

This is fine however my issue is that a user can be part of multiple teams, and when a given user is on only one team, the UI does not pass a team-id header in the request. In this case the api is (unfortunately) designed to pick only the active team.
My issue is: How can I get access to the user object sending the request? The middleware has not yet run and so the user is not available in the request object.
I am using the tymon/jwt-auth package for jwt tokens.

You need global scope: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#global-scopes

The problem is I have is the dynamic value (teamId) which would need to be applied to the globalScope is a value I cannot extract. I need to figure out how to get the user associated with the request first.

auth()->user()->teamId

This does not work as the RouteServiceProvider runs before the user is authenticated.

Yes, delete this from provider and make global scope for item.

please test it in the provider
$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

@alirezaalizade Yes, this works when I send a request however it does not work in tests. I will check why not. Thank you for helping.
